# Unity - Overriding GameObject's position attribute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overriding, gameobject

I have a complex GameObject (i.e. it is a parent to many other game objects) and I want to override its position attribute.

For example take the following game object

ParentGameObject
-Child1
-Child2

Now I want to position ParentGameObject with respect to the position of Child2, i.e. when I set ParentGameObject.transform.position it should reposition all elements with respect to Child2

Setting parent object's position to zero should actually position Child2, but whole gameobject should move.

[image]

Comment: More explanation is really appreciated. I really don't understand your requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by "with respect to"? Do you mean Child2 should not move, but all other objects?

Comment: I'm going to have to go along with the vote to close unless you can elaborate a little more

Comment: I have added an image, if this helps?
I actually have to reposition child2 and all the other game objects with child2

Comment: OK. Now I get it. You want the center/pivot of the parent object to be at the center of the object2. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. Never came to my mind, it was that simple to ask. Sorry for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want.

To move the center/pivot of the parent gameobject to one of the child gameobject.

```
Vector3 object2Pos = Object2.transform.position;
int deltaX = object2Pos.x;
int deltaY = object2Pos.y;
int deltaZ = object2Pos.z;
foreach(GameObject childObj in parentGameObject.Children)
{
    childObj.transform.position.x -= deltaX;
    childObj.transform.position.y -= deltaY;
    childObj.transform.position.z -= deltaZ;
}
//Now to bring back all objects where ever they were,
parentGameObject.transform.position.x += deltaX;
parentGameObject.transform.position.y += deltaY;
parentGameObject.transform.position.z += deltaZ;
```

I am not sure about the exact syntax. I will correct it, however this is the logic.

Comment: I get the logic, I can do that by creating my own SetPosition() function, but I wanted to know the way to override the position attribute so I can implement this logic there.

ParentObject.transform.position should do all this stuff, is there a way to accomplish this ?

Comment: If you want to override, you should create your own class that inherits GameObject. Well that will not be something you wanted to do, since you won't be able to work on visual editor then. Why don't you use the function itself?

Comment: @mdanishs _"but I wanted to know the way to override the position attribute so I can implement this logic there"_ - that is a bad idea.  You would be applying this specific scenario to everything which would be rather  catastrophic